# Angularjs route not calling the corresponding route's controller/view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have an Angulrjs application and in the app.js I have the following `config` like below:

```
 .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
```

I am using `ng-route` and in my app.js `run` function I call a backend API which redirects me to a login page and once I enter my credentials it calls back the UI on the following address

`http://hostname.company.net/?token=24OzjW%2FKZVfkiV%2Bku22T0ag%3D%3D`

Now the page is blank instead of routing to the `/`. I have mapped the `/` with `MainController` but the controller and view is not getting mapped. If I print the `$location.path` the value is `/`.

Even if I reload the screen, the page is blank. Only when I remove the `?token=...` and hit refresh I am getting the screen.

If I change the url to anything else, then it is working fine. If the route is a valid url, then corresponding controllers/view is called else MainController/MainView is getting called.

My config entry for handling the `/` is like below:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    resolve: {
      message: function (authService) {
        return authService.authenticateUser();
      }
    }
  });
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong or how to proceed as I am completely clueless on this bug.

Comment: Are you explicitly importing ngRoute? It is not a part of the default AngularJS package.

Comment: No. I am using the default implementation.

Comment: Please refer to this.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: I am using the same `ngRoute`. The route is perfectly working for all the conditions except for the mentioned url

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Removed incorrect information to avoid any potential misleading.

Keeping this here for now due to comment thread.

Comment: But when Angular see that the pattern is `www.yoururl.com/?parameter=somevalue` and there is no config entry why does'nt it route to the `/`?

Comment: Hmm. It is routing to `/` if it's showing `$location.path` as `/`, but it may not have the views and controllers properly configured. Where are you specifying the view's template and the controller for route `/`?

Comment: Added the config entry for handling the `/` request

Comment: Could you please show your whole code?

It's possible you're confusing how angular's client side routing works vs back-end routing. Angular does client-side routing using a hashbang url. 

'/' redirects to `www.yoururl.com/#/`

This may be a part of your problem, but without seeing the rest of your code I can't really tell. 

See [my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wofsh6zn/).
And [this article](http://sidazad.tumblr.com/post/92336467073/demystifying-angularjs-routing-html5-and).

Comment: Additionally, as mentioned by Sauhard above, from Angular 1.2 onwards, $routeProvider requires the ngRoute module to work, so you must include angular-router in your index.html as well as inject ngRoute as a dependency.